# How do I check if a var is a Tuple in Swift?

Tags: swift, syntax, tuples, typechecking

Reading the Type Casting section of the [Swift Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338) I see I use the `is` keyword to type check variables.

```
func isString(test: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return test is String
}
```

It seems when I try something similar to check for a Tuple containing three NSNumber objects, I receive a 'Tuple does not conform to protocol `AnyObject`'. Is there any way to check if a variable contains a Tuple?

```
func isTuple(test: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return test is (NSNumber, NSNumber, NSNumber) // error
}
```

Comment: Well you have no return type for your function so that would be a good place to start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use [`AnyObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html) here because a [tuple](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID448) is not an instance of a class type.

> - `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
> - `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

<sub>From [The Swift Programming Guide - Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)</sub>

Instead, try using the more general `Any` type:

```
func isTuple(test: Any?) -> Bool {
    return test is (NSNumber, NSNumber, NSNumber)
}

isTuple("test") // false
let tuple: (NSNumber, NSNumber, NSNumber) = (Int(), Int(), Int())
isTuple(tuple) // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
func isTuple(test: Any?) -> Bool{

    return test is (NSNumber, NSNumber, NSNumber)
}
```

Comment: This is redundant; there's no need for an extra `if` statement when `is` returns a `Bool` on its own.